# Cross-Thread access of a field in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

If a class has an array, it doesn't really matter what of. Now one thread is adding data to said array, while another thread needs to process the data that is already in it. With my limited knowledge of multithreading, how could this work? The first problem I can think of is if an item is added while the other thread is processing what's still there. At first I thought that wouldn't be a problem, the processor thread would get it next time it processed, but then I realized that while the processor thread removes items it's already processed, the adding thread would not receive this change, possibly (?) wreaking havoc. Is there any good way to implement this behavior?

Comment: It might matter what type the contents are, and you don't specify how 'Adding to' and 'Removing from' the array is implemented. In the end, you just shouldn't use an array here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've described is basically the [Reader Writers Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem). If you want to take care of multithreading, you're either going to need a concurrent collection, or use of a lock. The simplest implementation of a lock would just be locking an object

```
private Object myLock = new Object();

public MyClass ReadFromSharedArray()
{
lock(myLock)
{
//do whatever here
}

}

public void WriteToSharedArray(MyClass data)
{
lock(myLock)
{
//Do whatever here
}

}
```

There are better locks such as ReadWriterSlim locks but this sort of basic implementation should be a good starting point.

Also you mentioned adding/removing from arrays, I'm assuming you meant Lists (or better yet a Queue) - there's a [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)which could be a good replacement.

Comment: In reality, I am indeed using a Queue. I just simplified to array. Would I need to do anything special with the ConcurrentQueue or should I just use it as if there was no multithreading?

Comment: If all you're doing is reading/writing a concurrent queue is going to be fine.